# How do multi-element attacks interact with death saves?

Tags: dnd-5e

There are a lot of spells and even weapons the have multiple damage types in the same attack. For example, Meteor Swarm has 20d6 bludgeoning and 20d6 fire damage.

Let's say an unfortunate PC gets hit with meteor swarm and has 90 max hp, he first takes the bludgeoning damage of 91 and then the fire damage of 85. does this all register as 1 hit and become unconscious or would he become unconscious from the bludgeoning damage and then take the failed death saves from the fire damage?

In short: do multi element attacks count as 1 hit or does each element count as a different hit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**All the damage from one attack roll or save applies at once.**

When an attack deals multiple types of damage, all that damage is applied to the target at once.

In the case of your example, the total amount of damage taken by the attack is 91 + 85 damage (176 damage). The unfortunate PC makes a single saving throw, fails, and takes the specified damage. Only one save is made, so the damage hits as one and therefore becomes unconscious.

Let us take a different example; eldritch blast. At higher levels, eldritch blast can fire multiple beams, *each rolling a separate attack roll*. If a PC is attacked by two beams, and was brought to 0 hp by the first beam, but then is hit by the second, it would be a failed death save. This is because it counts as *two separate attacks.*

The reason it is split into separate damage types is for *resistances and vulnerabilities*. If your PC is resistant to a specific type of damage, then you can look at the separate damage types and apply the resistance to that portion of the damage roll.

The fact that the damage for Meteor Swarm is split into two numbers has no effect on the number of attacks/saves rolled, and so it all registers as one hit.